# Magento 2, plugin for MaintenanceEnableCommand does not get executed

Tags: magento2, plugin, command-line, maintenance

Considering below in etc/di.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Setup\Console\Command\MaintenanceEnableCommand">
        <plugin name="custom_maintenance" type="Custom\Module\Console\Command\MaintenanceEnableCommand" />
    </type>
</config>
```

wondering why below in `Custom\Module\Console\Command\MaintenanceEnableCommand` path does not get executed?

```
public function afterIsEnable(\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\MaintenanceEnableCommand $subject)
    {
        echo "in plugin";

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 Plugins (Interceptors) only work on `public` functions. The function `isEnable()` is `protected`

Magento's documentation on Plugins can be found here for further understanding - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html